# Пунктуация в песне «Листья жгут»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, поэзия, междометие

Нужна эта запятая в словах песни «Листья жгут»?

> Ах(,) зачем, той любви в наказанье, листья жгут, листья жгут, листья жгут?

Comment: Ах зачем, той любви в наказанье листья жгут, листья жгут, листья жгут?

Comment: Не пробовали текст песни найти? Там можно списать правильный ответ.

Comment: Негде его найти.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из словарей:
[**ах**](https://znachenie-slova.ru/%D0%B0%D1%85) (междометие, разг.) — употребляется при выражении сильных, обычно неожиданных чувств: радости, горя, испуга, сожаления, удивления, восхищения, возмущения.
Ах, как красиво!

***Ах,** зачем эта ночь так была хороша* (Н. А. фон Риттер, романс).

***Ах,** зачем я на свет появился,

**Ах,** зачем меня мать родила...*
Слова и музыка неизвестных авторов

***Ах,** зачем той любви в наказанье

Листья жгут, листья жгут, листья жгут?*
Н. Олев

Автор стихов все-таки ставит запятую после "ах".
А вот запятые, имеющиеся после "зачем" и "в наказанье", никаких споров не вызывают — они не нужны (без инверсии: Ах, зачем жгут листья в наказанье той любви?).

[Листья жгут](http://www.notarhiv.ru/ruskomp/dunaevskiymaxim/noty/1%20(16).pdf) (Нотный архив России)